# Ter duas versões do Python no OSX, sem sobrescrever

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, instalador, osx

Há alguma maneira de instalar a versāo 3.x do Python sem sobrescrever a versão pré-instalada (essencial) do OSX?

Eu já conheço o ***virtualenv*** mas gostaria de evitá-lo, até porque eu só uso Python para estudar.

Há alguma maneira de manter as duas versões paralelas e "vivendo em harmonia"?

Eu imagino que teria como fazer algo assim:

Iniciar Python 2

> ```
> MBP:~ jbueno$ python
> ```

Iniciar Python 3

> ```
> MBP:~ jbueno$ python3
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta instalar Homebrew pelo terminal (precisa do Xcode instalado):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Depois basta instalar o Python 3 através do comando `brew`:

```
brew install python3
```

Para executar algo usando Python 3 basta usar o comando `python3` em vez de apenas `python`.

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: No link http://brew.sh você pode ter mais detalhes, é apenas um instalador de pacotes.